# UIImagePickerController Unaccounted memory saved

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uikit

I'm allowing a user to pick a video from his/her library. When the photo library opens, it seems about 1.5Mb is added to Documents and data if I were to go look in settings->General->Usage. Once the user chooses the video and it's compressed, a total of about 4.5Mb is added to Documents and data. My problem is this data/memory never to seems to release. This is all being added before any kind of saving is done. So the documents and data usage amount keeps going up and up and I'm not sure why. I'm pretty sure everything is being released.

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
 {
//[super viewDidAppear:animated];
      if (IsFirstCall) {

          UIImagePickerController *uploadPick = [[[UIImagePickerController alloc] init] autorelease] ;
          uploadPick.delegate = self;
          uploadPick.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
          uploadPick.mediaTypes = [[[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:(NSString *) kUTTypeMovie, nil] autorelease];   

         [self presentViewController:uploadPick animated:YES completion:nil];
         //[uploadPick release];
    }
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. I don't think its possible to use the file manager instrument on an actual phone, it seems its only works for the simulator. I spent a lot of time trying to figure out why this is happening.

Comment: I did, it is set to Yes under Build Settings

Comment: That is Objective-C Automatic Reference Counting?

Comment: You say you enabled ARC (Automatic Reference Counting). For consistency, since it must still be compiling, you should remove your autorelease statements from your code. And calling the `super` on this method is recommended. Are you using Instruments to check for memory leaks?

Comment: ARC forbids autoreleasing or releasing anything when enabled.

Answer (score 1):

A possibility of what is happening here is actually temporary files being saved. You mention that compressing the video seems to trigger this increase in space.

There's two ways that you could confirm this by one of two methods. By restarting the device you're testing on. Temporary items will get cleared away by the system either when additional space is required, or when the system shuts down.

The other method (and probably more informative) is to investigate the Application through the Xcode organiser. You can do this by selecting the Application on the device and browsing the Applications directory structure. Each application gets 3 directories, /Documents, /Library and /tmp.

For intensive operations, that may require the use of a lot of memory, certain libraries will save completed data out to disk, in order to free up memory. Once the operation is completed it will then pass you back a block of data that either references the data in the temporary file, or has the completed data loaded back into memory. This process is completely transparent to the user and developer, and takes advantage of the large amount of flash memory, rather than relying completely on the comparatively limited RAM.

In the event that it is not a temporary file, but rather something sitting within the Documents folder of the Application (or even the library), it could be useful to download it to your computer and attempt to investigate its contents, as it may give you some clues as to what is happening.

Hope this helps

Edited a point for clarity

Comment: So I restarted the phone and unfortunately the data was still there. I will try the other method soon. Do I need to use instruments to use the organiser?

Comment: OK good news, From the organizer then from my phone I clicked on my app to see the documents and in the tmp folder is a file called trim.IEKOAK.MOV, so it seems that right after I select a video and after it compresses, this video is being saved to my tmp folder. The problem now is why? I'm not telling/coding anything to save that video.

Comment: It is extremely likely (almost certain I'd say) that the Image Picker library (when dealing) with movies has to save them to /tmp in order to be able to complete any operations required, such as compression and trimming. The reason for this is because of how large a movie has the potential to become. If you have a 200MB movie, attempting to contain the entirety of that in RAM whilst performing an operation upon it is not an optimal use of resources. The likely order of operation is something like: chunk from original movie > _operation_ > save chunk to /tmp > repeat until operation completed

Comment: You could periodically go through and clear the /tmp directory yourself, as the chances are, once you have actually saved the movie yourself, you'll no longer need that file.